# Using more memory in MySQL Server

Tags: mysql

**Summary:**
I haven't yet been able to get MySQL to use more than 1 core for a select statement and it doesn't get above 10 or 15 GB of RAM.

**The machine:**
I have a dedicated Database server running MariaDB using MySQL 5.6. The machine is strong with 48 cores and 192GB of RAM.

**The data:**
I have about 250 million rows in one large table (also several other tables ranging from 5-100 million rows). I have been doing a lot of reading from the tables, sometimes inserting into a new table to denormalize the data a bit. I am not setting this system up as a transactional system, rather, it will be used more similarly to a data warehouse with few connections.

**The problem:**
When I look at my server's stats, it looks like CPU is at around 70% for one core with a select query running, and *memory is at about 5-8%*. There is no IO waiting, so I am convinced that I have a problem with MySQL memory allocation. After searching on how to increase the usage of memory in MySQL I have noticed that the config file may be the way to increase memory usage.

**The solution I have tried based on my online searching:**
I have changed the tables to MyISAM engine and added many indexes. This has helped performance, but querying these tables is still incredibly slow. The write speed using load data infile is very fast, however, running a mildly complex select query takes hours or even days.

I have also tried adjusting the following configurations:

```
key-buffer-size                = 64G
read_buffer_size              = 1M
join_buffer_size               = 4294967295
read_rnd_buffer_size           = 2M
key_cache_age_threshold        = 400
key_cache_block_size          = 800
myisam_data_pointer_size       = 7
preload_buffer_size            = 2M
sort_buffer_size               = 2M
myisam_sort_buffer_size        = 10G
bulk_insert_buffer_size        = 2M
myisam_repair_threads          = 8
myisam_max_sort_file_size      = 30G
max-allowed-packet             = 256M
tmp-table-size                 = 32M
max-heap-table-size            = 32M
query-cache-type               = 0
query-cache-size               = 0
max-connections                = 500
thread-cache-size              = 150
open-files-limit               = 65535
table-definition-cache         = 1024
table-open-cache               = 2048
```

These config changes have slightly improved the amount of  memory being used, but I would like to be able to use 80% of memory or so... or as much as possible to get maximum performance. Any ideas on how to increase the memory allocation to MySQL?

Comment: It will never use more than one core for one query. One thread per connection it is.

Comment: Agreed, I have been realizing it won't use more cores in a single select, that is why I have been focusing on trying to get it to use more memory.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already no IO waiting you are using a good amount of memory. Your buffers also seem quite big. So I would doubt that you can have significant CPU savings with using additional memory. You are limited by the CPU power of a single core.

Two strategies could help:

1. Use EXPLAIN or query analyzers to find out if you can optimize your queries to save CPU time. Adding missing indexes could help a lot. Sometimes you also might need combined indexes.
2. Evaluate an alternative storage engine (or even database) that is better suited for analytical queries and can use all of your cores. MariaDB supports InfiniDB but there are also other storage engines and databases available like Infobright, MonetDB.

Answer (score 0):

Use show global variables like "%thread%" and you may get some clues on enabling thread concurrency options.

read_rnd_buffer_size at 2M tested at 16384 with your data may produce significant reduction in time required to complete your query.